# PCRE cannot match Certain UTF-8 characters against \X escape sequence

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding, pcre

I am conducting some tests on UTF-8 and PCRE and found that the following regex cannot match certain characters like the one `E1 8D 9F` (character `፟`).

```
return preg_match_all( '/\X/u' , $string , $matches , PREG_SET_ORDER );
```

`$string` is exact one UTF-8 character. Works with many characters but I have a list of code points that fail this regex. Any clue?

Edit: All the characters that fail with above regex appear perfectly valid when I check them byte by byte. Is this a bug or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be a bug in your version of PHP - it works fine in PHP 5.4 but not all previous versions. Here is an [online code sampling](http://3v4l.org/AiZ2L) of which ones it works for.

btw this answer is based on assuming you meant [character U+135F](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/135F/index.htm) which has utf-8 encoding of 0xE1 0x8D 0x9F .

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/135F/index.htm

Comment: Yes its `U+135F` character. So, on my PHP 5.3.8, it didnt match, as the online test showed `Result is :0`. BTW, thanks for the answer and thanks for the code testing site link.

Answer (score 1):

The PHP documentation says that `\X` is equivalent to `(?>\PM\pM*)`.
I believe U+135F does not match this.
See http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php

Since PCRE 8.32, `\X` matches Unicode's definition of an Extended Grapheme Cluster.
See http://bugs.exim.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1279

PHP5.4.14 includes PCRE 8.32.